# Javascript/jQuery search for a "minute:second" time using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an array of variables all containing text. I want to select only the items containing a minute-second marker, eg. "3:00", "4:01", "0:23". I understand how to go through the array, I just need to know how to implement [this regex](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=332).

Just to be safe, here it is:

`^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$`

I'm trying to implement it in this:

```
$.each(comments, function(i, val) { //Go through array with jQuery
    //Remove from array if instance of "minute:second" is not found
});
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Dave Thomas requested examples. They are all YouTube comments. Examples of a comment with the minute:time and then one without are below. All taken from an example video.

1. "1:00 Fifa 12 comentator?"
2. "ROOOOOOOONEY <3"

EDIT2:

```
for (var i = 0, len = comments.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(!(comments[i].test(/(([0-5][0-9])|[0-9])\:[0-9]{2,2}/))){
        comments.splice(i,1);
    }
}​
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of these variables/strings?

Comment: They are all YouTube comments that I got through the API.

Comment: Great; could you add some examples to your question?

Comment: I added them in the question. I just thought examples would be kind of useless since I want this to work on any given YouTube video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to be using the native [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function for fitlering arrays (there is a shim for older browsers in the link) instead of [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and you can test a regexp against a string using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
var pattern = /(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))/;
comments = comments.filter(function(str){
    return pattern.test(str);
});
```

Comment: +1 but The times will be in the middle of the content, so you'll need to remove the `^` and `$`

Comment: Thanks @fudgey. I didn't see the edit showing the sample input.

Comment: Ok, this isn't working but that's probably because I'm thinking it works a different way. Does this just remove the non-matching strings from the array? Or does this return a boolean meaning I should use it as an if statement for each item to decide whether or no to remove it?

Comment: @MarkLyons This removes the non-matching strings from the array.

Comment: When I print the array after this, nothing is removed.

Comment: @MarkLyons The `filter` function doesn't modify the array, it just returns a new one. So if you want it to modify `comments` you just overwrite it. I updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O., I know you've answered and all, but if you have a moment I'd really appreciate some insight on what I think should be a simple problem. Is there any way to take the first instances of a minute:second format from each comment that was returned in the first part and put them into an array?

Comment: @MarkLyons Yeah! You should not use test anymore then though. You want to use something like `var matches = str.match(pattern);` Then `matches[0]` should contain the match of the regex and you can do `if(matches){ arr.push(matches[0]); return true; }else return false;`. Let me know if you're able to get it working or have trouble. I'm about to log off for the night though, so I won't be able to reply until morning.

Comment: I'm using the same regex pattern and it always gets only the middle 3 positions in the string. Eg. 26:00 goes to 6:0 and 25:50 goes to 5:5. Maybe I should use a different pattern?

Comment: Actually, just got it. Used Dave Thomas' regex and it seemed to work. Not sure why, but it did. :P Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, if you don't mind a more native-JavaScript approach:

```
var comments = ["01:00 Fifa 12 comentator?", "ROOOOOOOONEY <3"];

for (var i = 0, len = comments.length; i < len; i++) {
    return comments[i].test(/(([0-5][0-9])|[0-9])\:[0-9]{2,2}/);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sVsrP/).

Explanation of the regex:

```
(([0-5][0-9])|[0-9])\:[0-9]{2,2}
```

- `([0-5][0-9])` essentially identifies the minutes portion of the time-string, on the grounds that minutes can only ever be from `0` (or `00`) to `59`, this searches for a single digit from `0-5` followed by a `0-9`.
- `|` indicates an 'or', it will identify the previous double-digit sequence from `00` to `59` or the subsequent sequence.
- `[0-9]` again, this identifies the range of `0-9`, so identifies single-digit minutes.
- `\:` because a colon is a special character in regex the back-slash escapes the colon, and allows for a search of the literal `:` character.
- `[0-9]{2,2}` searches for a two-digit sequence of characters, each of which will be from the sequence of `0-9`.

---

**Edited** to update the above code:

```
var comments = [/*...rather a lot...*/]
    timelyComments = [];

for (var i = 0, len = comments.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (comments[i].test(/(([0-5][0-9])|[0-9])\:[0-9]{2,2}/)){
        timelyComments.push(comments[i]);
    }
}

console.log(timelyComments);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sVsrP/1/).

References:

- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: So that, return part will return true if an instance of the time format is found? I'm trying to remove non matches. I'll edit my question with how I'm trying to implement your response.

Comment: Removing non-matches from the comments array?

Comment: Comments that don't contain an instance of the minute:time thing I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm getting a `test is not defined` error in my console. Which is odd I guess because I thought it was a function/method.

Comment: What browser/OS? Does it work any better with [`match()` (updated demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sVsrP/2/)?

Comment: @MarkLyons (and implicitly David) This is because `test` is a method on RegExp, not on Strings. It's used like `regexp.test(str)`.

Comment: With regards to @PaulP.R.O.'s comment: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sVsrP/3/). Also, Paul, thanks! I'd never noticed that I'd been using `test()` the wrong way round... =/

Comment: Your regexes will match '6:10' in '596:103', and allow '40:99'. Use word boundaries and the same expression on both sides: `/\b([0-5]?\d)\:([0-5]?\d)\b/`. Alternatively, accept any value in both sides, not < 60, and convert time accordingly (62:30 -> 1:02:30). YouTube videos can be hours long too.